# Simple conditional LINQ query in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have recently migrated this code to Entity Framework 4 and it is failing. Obviously if status does not have a value, return all matches, if it does have a value match ones where `user.StatusID == 1`.

```
return users.SingleOrDefault(
                user =>
                user.Username == username &&
                user.EncryptedPassword == password &&
                (!status.HasValue || user.StatusID == 1)
                );
```

Exception returned:

```
ArgumentException: The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Int32'
Parameter name: value
```

However, removing the conditional test and it works fine:

```
return users.SingleOrDefault(
                user =>
                user.Username == username &&
                user.EncryptedPassword == password &&
                user.StatusID == 1
                );
```

Any ideas? How do you perform conditional testing in EF 4? Surely not separate if lines?

I use these conditional tests time and time again in Linq to Sql; it is really odd as to why this is not functioning in EF 4. There must be something simple going wrong, perhaps there is a recommended alternate way of doing things in EF 4.0.

Thanks for your help guys,
Graham

Comment: what the `Edm.Int32`? is it your own implementation of `System.Int32` ?

Comment: @Stecya : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387164.aspx , seems to be some internals of EF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by a combination of two things.

1. Doing a simple null test.
2. Testing the local cast `status` variable *without* the `.Value` method.

Both must be in place otherwise it will continue to fail with the error! It would have been nice to test the value property, but I guess the query must be really simple - quite interesting!

```
return users.SingleOrDefault(
                user =>
                user.Username == username &&
                user.EncryptedPassword == password &&
                (status == null || user.StatusID == (int) status)
                );
```

I will wait for any better implementation otherwise accept my own answer. But thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: EF looks better and better... Thank you for the solution, it bit me today.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating separate variable for `!status.HasValue` and using this instead in query?

I think problem here is that EF tries to pass your status variable as parameter into the query and then do the logic in the SQL itself. Try checking what SQL is generated.

Comment: Wow, that passes, declaring `var test = !status.HasValue` then testing test. But it's not nice. However it has led me to try every casting and bracketing trick I can think of because surely if it works like this, it can work in-line, they both resolve false. Hum. Any further thoughts?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the fact `status` is not an int; and it's getting confused comparing one enum and one int type in the one construct.  No casting can function either because it is nullable :(

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to doing the null check within the where clause would be to seperate out the optional parameter and only apply it if required.

e.g.

```
    var data = users.Where(
        user =>
            user.Username == username &&
            user.EncryptedPassword == password
        );

    if (status.HasValue)
    {
        data = data.Where(user => user.StatusID == status.Value);
    }

    return data.FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't think it'll offer much over your current solution other than a little more readability.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've already found a solution...

However, just fyi... i have no problem with the following line in VS 2010

```
  Nullable<int> status = 0;
  String username = "Alexandre 2";

    var test = _context.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.FirstName == username && (!status.HasValue || c.ContactID == 1));
```

I get no errors and the Contact object i expect is return ... so if anything, it makes me wonder what is the type of your user.StatusID field?

best of luck

Answer (score 0):

what is  `status.HasValue` ? if status is a field of `User` you should call it like this :`user.status.HasValue`

so simply do this :

```
if(status.HasValue)
    return users.SingleOrDefault(
                user =>
                user.Username == username &&
                user.EncryptedPassword == password &&
                user.StatusID == 1
                );

    return users.SingleOrDefault(
                user =>
                user.Username == username &&
                user.EncryptedPassword == password
                );
```

Comment: Hi Farzin, it's a nullable int, and rather a field of the enclosing method.

Comment: edited, I know this is not a common solution, but works for you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enclose user.StatusID == 1 in additional set of parentheses, as I think currently EF tries to apply || operation to status.HasValue and user.StatusId and then compare the result to 1.

Comment: Alas, no luck. Good thinking though.

Answer (score 0):

At the first galance it appeare like this in my mind:

```
return users.SingleOrDefault(
                user =>
                user.Username == username &&
                user.EncryptedPassword == password &&
                (status == null || user.StatusID == 1)
                );
```

but when I look at it more i feel it's wrong so What about?

```
return users.SingleOrDefault(
    user =>
    user.Username == username &&
    user.EncryptedPassword == password &&
    status != null &&
    user.StatusID == 1)
  );
```

what is the exactly business logic behind it?

Comment: Ah, well, your second query will always enforce the requirement of a status, which is not necessarily the case. `status` could be `null` and in that case, I want to fetch all entries. That's why I use the `||` operator.